# Sequence point, function call and undefined behaviour

Tags: c++

**main.cpp**

```cpp
const int& f(int& i ) { return (++i);}
int main(){   
    int i = 10;
    int a = i++ + i++; //undefined behavior
    int b = f(i) + f(i); //but this is not
}
```

compile

```
$ g++ main.cpp -Wsequence-point
```

statement `int a = i++ + i++;` is undefined behaviour.

statement `int b = f(i) + f(i);` is not undefined .
why?

Comment: Who said the second is not UB?

Comment: it should be UB. but g++ didn't complain with flag -Wsequence-point

Comment: Compilers cannot always detect UB even with the flag.

Comment: makes sense, for compiler to detect UB for second case, it has to see if function f() will modify i or not. looks like not an easy step to do.

Comment: `-Wsequence-point` warns only about possibly undefined behavior due to unsequenced evaluation/side effects on the same scalar. It doesn't warn about unspecified evaluation order due to indeterminate sequencing in general. The evaluation of a function call (including all the evaluations as part of that call) is always at least _indeterminately_ sequenced with all other evaluations in the calling context, not _unsequenced_ (which is what causes undefined behavior).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> statement `int b = f(i) + f(i);` is not undefined . why?

No, the second statement will result in unspecified behavior. You can confirm this [here](https://godbolt.org/z/94e3vYeao). As you'll see in the above [linked demo](https://godbolt.org/z/94e3vYeao), gcc gives the output as `23` while msvc gives `24` for the same program.

Comment: The version with function calls is ***not*** undefined behavior; it is *unspecified* behavior.

Comment: @j6t Ah i see. I often forget this for functions. Thanks for the correction and reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-c++11, we use [Sequence_point_rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Sequence_point_rules):

> Pre-C++11 Undefined behavior
>
> 1. Between the previous and next sequence point, the value of any object in a memory location must be modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression, otherwise the behavior is undefined.

> Pre-C++11 Rules
> 3) There is a sequence point after the copying of a returned value of a function and before the execution of any expressions outside the function.

- In `int a = i++ + i++;`, `i` is modified twice
- In `int b = f(i) + f(i);`, there are sequence point with function call. `i` is modified only once between the sequence call. so no UB.
  Note though that order of evaluation is unspecified so (evaluation of result) `f(i)` might happens after or before the second `f(i)`, which might lead to different result depending of optimization/compiler and even between call.

Since C++11, we use "Sequenced before" rules, which is a similar way disallows `i++ + i++` but allows `f(i) + f(i)`.